# How to configure spring profiles in Netbeans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netbeans

I am running a [Spring boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) Java app in [Netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/) 9.0 which has two [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) (test, production). I need to run the project in 'test' profile instead of the 'default'

I have tried the following setups

**Setup 1**

Project (Right click) > Properties > Run > Arguments

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

**Setup 2**

Project (Right click) > Properties > Actions > Run Projects > Activate Profiles

```
test
```

The configuration doesn't work correctly and I am getting the following message

*"No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default"*

Could you please help me to set up this configuration

Answer (score 1):

After poking around a bit, I found that from Netbeans 8.1 and up you can do the following to set a Spring profile:

Right click your application -> Run Maven -> Goals -> In the "Properties" section set:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active={your profile name here}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Dude, not project properties. In the "Projects Tab" -> your project name -> Run Maven -> Goals... -> In the "Properties" section set: the profile as the template above

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  configuring profiles in the `application.properties` or `application.yml` in your spring boot app?

Please read this documentation
[Spring Boot Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: yes, there are already two profiles configured in the Java app using application.yml. When I run the project in Netbeans it is using the 'default' profile, but instead, I want to configure to 'test' profile

Comment: Annotate your configuration class with the profile you want to run. It is shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have installed [this plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/67888/nb-springboot) to NetBeans.
Then right click on the Project -> Properties:

[image]

**Important**: The argument starts with "--" (not "-D") since it's a spring boot command.